# ArrayList Size is Zero - Accessing from other Class

Tags: java, arraylist, static

I have two files `TestingArrayList.java` and `ArrayListClass`. I am trying to access `ArrayList object` created in `ArrayListClass` from `TestingArrayList` class. Even though the list is populated in `ArrayListClass`. `size()` method on ArrayList object from `TestingArrayList` is returning `zero`.

**TestingArrayList.java**

```
class TestingArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ArrayListClass.justList.size());
    }

}
```

**ArrayListClass.java**

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayListClass {

    public static ArrayList<String> justList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        justList.add("I am working ");
        while(true);
    }
}
```

How can I access ArrayList efficiently from another class? Am I handling the ArrayList appropriately or is there something wrong with this ?

Comment: Which `main` are you running?

Comment: I am running two mains, at the same time. on  different consoles.

Comment: The `main` method of `ArrayListClass` is never called (as a proof, it doesn't hang on your infinite while loop). What you want to use is a static initialization block.

Comment: @saikumar No you aren't.

Comment: First `ArrayListClass` and then `TestingArrayList`

Comment: @immibis why use java then?

Comment: @immibis still, everyone **should** use it

Comment: i agree this is not a pretty way of handeling the problem but i cant imagine what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BogdanM. I am trying to use this way of handling ArrayList in a project I am working on.

Comment: `while(true);` ; ______ ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start two `main` methods, then you are starting two separate virtual machines. Both VMs have their own objects and static variables.

If you want to run both `main` methods parallel, you probably want something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread() { run() { 
        ArrayListClass.main(null);
    }}.start();

    new Thread() { run() { 
        TestingArrayList.main(null);
    }}.start();
}
```

Only start this `main`

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the list in order for it to actually be diferent from null

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(ArrayListClass.justList.size()); // ArrayListClass has nothing initilized in it.
}
```

Now you need to initliaze a static list! ([Static Initialization Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks))
for that append in your ArrayListClass  ann initlaisation

```
static{
        System.out.println("Init list here"); // this one is called once only.
    }
```

Read more about blocks: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html
and [Static Initializers And Static Methods In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692977/static-initializers-and-static-methods-in-java)

Comment: This is actually a `snippet` from a project I am working on, There I cannot use `static blocks`

Comment: There I am populated the List when certain object gets created. I am accessing this list in a different class which is in different file. Static blocks work just once and before the main begins, I think.

Comment: Well yes then you can do what you want  with the list, you question was about the null pointer is this answere not fising null pointer?
Have  even glimpsed the links i posted? I recommand you for what you need to create a class using singlethon pattern and use that if you wanna use that object  over the application. but for your requirements this  resources should help if

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are running main method from `TestingArrayList.java`, so `justList` is not populated. Change main method in`ArrayListClass.java`  to be a constructor and then call it in the `TestingArrayList.java` main method before you are calling for `justList.size()`.

Comment: `justList` is `static`, if you want to populate it in the constructor, it's a bad idea to keep it `static`, because every time you create a new instance of the object, you will add new entries into the list.

Comment: I know. This could be useful when you count how many instances of particular class has been created. But what I understood from @sai_kumar question is that he wants to populate it ArrayListClass.java. Better way to do it is to create another public method in that class that will populate this static list. But here I cannot see any usage of what he is doing, so it can be done in constructor.